# typescript classes, interfaces and generics

Tags: typescript

I am writing 2 classes, `Project` and `User`, each of which has a `find` method that needs to call an api rest call

**attempt #1**

```
class Project {
  find(params) { 
    return request({url: "/api/Project", qs: params});
  }
}

class User {
  find(params) { 
    return request({url: "/api/User", qs: params});
  }
}
```

now, this is obviously not very good ;) There are no checks on the parameters, no types defined, duplicate code etc etc

**attempt #2**

```
class Base {
  constructor(private name:string) {
  } 

  find(options) { 
    return request({url: `/api/${this.name}`, qs: params});
  }
}

class Project extends Base{
  constructor() { super("Project"); }
}

class User {
  constructor() { super("User"); }    
}
```

so, slightly better. less code duplication. Still no type checking. Interfaces to the rescue ;)

**attempt#3**

```
interface IParams { token: string } 

class Base {
  constructor(private name:string) {
  } 

  find(params:IParams) { 
    return request({url: `/api/${this.name}`, qs: params});
  }
}

class Project extends Base{
  constructor() { super("Project"); }
}

class User extends Base {
  constructor() { super("User"); }    
}
```

this is where I started to hit some problems. The Project and User api params object both require the `token` property. However, they also require `userDd` and `projectId` to be set

At the moment, I need to add both of those to the IParams interface, which seems wrong.

attempt#4

```
interface IUserParams { userid:number, token: string } 
interface IProjectParams { projectid:number, token: string } 

interface IProject {
   find(params:IProjectParams)
}

interface IUser {
   find(params:IUserParams)
}

class Base {
  constructor(private name:string) {
  } 

  find(params) { // I have no idea on how to "type" params
    return request({url: `/api/${this.name}`, qs: params}); // likewise no idea on how to type the return value
  }
}

class Project extends Base implements IProject {
  constructor() { super("Project"); }
}

class User extends Base implements IUser {
  constructor() { super("User"); }    
}
```

However, this does not help : as the Base class defines the `find` method, how can the compiler verify that for user, `userid` and `token` are passed  - also, that *no other parameter* is passed, and likewise for project

This also led me onto thinking about the return value of the `find` method : for projects I want an array of `IPromiseModel`, and for user, `IUserModel`

I have tried chaning the `IProject` interface to read

```
interface IProject {
    find(params:IProjectParams):Promise<IProjectModel[]>
}
```

but I still can pass *any* property into the `params` - ie I can do

```
Project.find({token: "1234",foobar:true})
```

I suspect this is because I haven't defined a type for the parameter in the Base find

I *know* that generics must play a part in this, but for the life of me I cannot get a definition working that matches these requirements

I am using typescript 2.2.2

Comment: You are able to pass `any` into derived class methods because they hide the base method. This means that the declared type is actually that of the find methods in the derived classes.

Comment: that's what I thought / was hoping - but then why is the compiler allowing me to pass "foobar" as one of the properties of IProjectParams ?

Comment: If `Project` has the type of the class, the same reasoning applies.

Comment: FWIW I would just use a single function and some interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

With generics you can do this:

```
interface IParams { token: string }
interface IUserParams { userid:number, token: string }
interface IProjectParams { projectid:number, token: string }

class Base<TEntity, TParams extends IParams> {
    constructor(private name:string) {
    }

    find(params: TParams): Promise<TEntity[]> {
        return request({url: `/api/${this.name}`, qs: params});
    }
}

class Project extends Base<Project, IProjectParams> {
    constructor() { super("Project"); }
}

class User extends Base<User, IUserParams> {
    constructor() { super("User"); }
}

new User().find({
    userid: 123,
    token: 'test'
});
```

The constraint in the Base class `TParams extends IParams` here is optional, since you are not explicitly accessing the token property.

Comment: wow. thanks - I have been trying to use this structure . 

However, I've hit a couple of problems: 1) the 'find' method is returning a promise, so shouldn't the signature be " Promise<Array<TEntity>>", and #2  with unit tests and mocha, I now get an error compiling unit tests with "error TS2339: Property 'rejectedWith' does not exist on type 'Assertion'."

where my test is "Project.find({token:"invalidToken"}).should.be.rejectedWith({statusCode: 401});" - but a "Project.find({token:"validToken"}).then((data) => {" works just fine

Comment: Yeah, the return type should be as you said. About the error in the tests, I guess could be something related to the type definitions of this library.

Comment: Installing "@types/chai-as-promised" provides the type definitions needed by typescript.